# Change localization after redirecting

Tags: php, laravel

I wanna set localization in middleware, like if user is not authed redirect to login,
redirect works but next language is not changing like if current lang set as `fr` after redirecting it changes as `en`

here is code what I've tried `App:setLocale()` not effected

/Authenticate.php

```
protected function redirectTo($request)
    {

        if (! $request->expectsJson()) {
            App::setLocale('fr'); // I want to implement something like that, for all auth urls
            return route('login','fr');
        }
    }
```

Can someone help, how to change login,register ... language with current lang.

Comment: You are using `SESSIONS`  for set locale, in Authentication.

Comment: @STA No. `App::setLocale()` should working yeah? in this cases

Comment: Yes, David. In this case you need to set a default language for all users.

Answer (score 0):

Route returns and redirect to it does not occur

```
return redirect()->guest(route('login','fr'));
```